# Demo data from Odoov8 to Odoov10 community - res.partner

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have some demo data on `res.partner` model, which is from a module I'm migrating from v8 to v10 community.

An example data looks like this:

```
    <record id="f_req_partner_1" model="res.partner">
        <field name="name">Comercializadora M321, C.A.</field>
        <field name="vat">VEJ299868647</field>
        <field name="supplier">True</field>
        <field name="customer">True</field>
        <field name="type">invoice</field>
        <field name="street">Carretera Panamericana, KM1, Edif 1, piso 3, local C</field>
        <field name="street2">Urb. Delgado Chalbaud</field>
        <field name="country_id" ref="base.ve"/>
        <field name="is_company">True</field>
        <field name="zip">1090</field>
    </record>
```

But when I'm tryin to add this demo data (as it was for v8) throws me this:

```
ParseError: "default_get() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)" while parsing /home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/demo/demo_partners.xml:13, near
    <record id="f_req_partner_1" model="res.partner">
        <field name="name">Comercializadora M321, C.A.</field>
        <field name="vat">VEJ299868647</field>
        <field name="supplier">True</field>
        <field name="customer">True</field>
        <field name="type">invoice</field>
        <field name="street">Carretera Panamericana, KM1, Edif 1, piso 3, local C</field>
        <field name="street2">Urb. Delgado Chalbaud</field>
        <field name="country_id" ref="base.ve"/>
        <field name="is_company">True</field>
        <field name="zip">1090</field>
    </record>
```

So, I guess there is some mandatory field not added, then, which are the defaults for a partner in `res.partner` v10?

I can't find any example on any addon from this version.

What am I missing here, any ideas?

Comment: I believe the method `default_get` on `res.partner` is being called with two arguments: `self` and `fields`, where in the old API it was being called with four. So you need to port or `default_get` method on `res.partner` model to the new API in the module you are migrating.

Comment: Exactly, seems more of an error in the python code. Is there python code in this module for the model `res.partner`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, gonna post it